# python mobaxterm + Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: python-3.x, unix

I usually run a python script from mobaxterm. The process runs smoothly but today i got this error that I have never come across before. When i google it, nothing comes out.

Any ideas what 
"Illegal instruction (core dumped)" mean
?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

the issue is coming from our server- just got the info from our IT department. please ignore the question